# Pandas connect to DB2 server with SSL

Tags: python, ssl, db2, anaconda

So before my server started to use/enforce SSL I was able to connect by doing

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import ibm_db_sa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

eng = 'ibm_db_sa://{user}:{psw}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(
    user = user,
    psw=psw,
    host=host,
    port=port,
    db=db
)
engine = create_engine(eng)
sql = '''select * from table fetch first 10 rows only'''
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=engine)
```

So I can connect to the DB with SSL just fine using data studio and a .jks file, but can't connect anymore using Python. I tried editing the connection string to either

```
ibm_db_sa://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db};SECURITY=SSL;SSLServerCertificate={arm};
```

or

```
ibm_db_sa://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db};SECURITY=SSL;SSLCLIENTKEYSTOREDB={kdb};SSLCLIENTKEYSTASH={sth};
```

where arm, kdb and sth are paths on my local system where I have the corresponding files. ex "C:/Users/wizuriel/Documents/Trusted Sources/[file].kdb" (have tried surrounding the path in single quotes and with no quotes and no issue)

the error I get is

> (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI
>   Driver] SQL1109N  The specified DLL "GSKit Error: 202" could not be
>   loaded.  SQLSTATE=42724\r SQLCODE=-1109

looking up that GSKit error 202 people say it might be an issue with the path variables. I've tried editing my environment variables to point to \Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\icc64 where I see the GSK8 dlls and had no luck. So hoping someone might know what else I can try

[image]

Comment: please EDIT you question to include the *fixpack* and *version* of your Db2 client product (or Db2-server if it is a local server).  Use the db2level command (if that exists in your Db2-client) to find this information.

Comment: The 202 error means "Unable to open the key file or the Microsoft Certificate Store. Either the path was specified incorrectly or the file permissions did not allow the file to be opened, or the file format is incorrect. ". So you should print and examine the full connection string (you only show variable placeholders) and double check the paths (for keystore and stash), and if they need quoting for spaces etc.

Comment: I know the variables are correct (have verified against my connection string in data studio). I've tried putting the file path in single quotes and no quotes in the connection string and no change. The files don't have any permission issues I can see. Not sure how to get the DB2 info you requested

Comment: Search for the file `db2level.exe` on your workstation and run it in a command-window if you find it. It reports a few lines so copy paste those into your question.   If you reference a keystore(and stash) for CLI/odbc apps, know that these are *separate* from a java keystore and would be created/maintained by GSK. If your DataStudio SSL connection works correctly with the SSLServerCertificate method (i.e. no manually created keystore/stash needed), then python should also work (if the bitness of python, Db2-client,pandas all match).

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Your Db2 product is  fixpack 0  of Db2 v10.1 according to that db2level output.   That version did not support the SSLServerCertificate keyword for CLI applications (you need to be at least on V10.5 fixpack 8 client for that to work).  It is supposed to support SSL for non-java apps as long as GSK 8 is installed and properly configured, but you are probably wasting your time with that old version as many bugs have subsequently been fixed.  Most likely IBM will refuse to support you without an extended support contract.  Consider upgrading to a recent and supported Db2 version.

Comment: Despite the above, if you have GSK8 installed, the follow the advice for V10.1 at this page: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0053518.html